# Get the hostname of imported HTML

Tags: javascript, html

So I imported an html file using an HTML import in `index.html`:

```
<link rel="import" href="http://localhost:52008/importedFile.html">
```

My server which run this `index.html` is on `http://localhost:51165`. (I enabled CORS on `http://localhost:52008`)

If I put this script in the `importedFile.html`:

```
console.log(window.location.host);
```

The result would be "http://localhost:51165" instead of "http://localhost:52008".

**Is there a way to add a script in "importedFile.html"** to get its host(`http://localhost:52008`)?

Comment: Because the imported script uses `window` it will always log the location of the url the browser is viewing

Comment: is there any other way beside `window` that can solve this problem @Baksteen?

Comment: Not that I know of. Because the browser first imports the javascript before executing it. It is not executed on the server.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following JavaScript inside your `index.html` in `http://localhost:51165` to get the `host` of the imported document.

```
var getLocation = function(href) {
  var l = document.createElement("a");
  l.href = href;
  return l;
};
var l = getLocation(document.getElementsByTagName("link")[1].href); 
document.write(l.host);
```

This will use a virtual `<a>` tag to get the `host` of its `href`.

Check out this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3zr4a3qs/1/).